# Mac OS Desktop coordinate problem

Tags: display, desktop, mouse

I'm having a hard time working with Mac OS screen coordinates.  I can use **⌘+⇧+4** to get them, but each of my monitors does not have a unique coordinate system??!?

I have a desktop of 4 screens arranged in a 2x2 pattern. Each screen has a size of (2048 pixels x 1152 pixels).  (And the Apple Menu Bar is on the top-left screen).

**⌘+⇧+4** gives the upper-left of each screen as (0,0) and the lower right as (2048,1152).

But each screen does that!

Technically, the coordinate system "should" run from (0,0) to (4096,2304). How do I differentiate the coordinates of the individual monitors?

Furthermore, when I create a window at (500,500) it creates it in the top-left monitor at (500,652)

So I just don't understand what's going on. How can I get an accurate coordinate map for the Mac OS desktop with multiple monitors?

Comment: *when I create a window at (500,500) it creates it in the top-left monitor at (500,652)* how are you “creating” a window? maybe if you give us some more insight about what the problem is? :)

Comment: @Martin, well, I'm using a `MAAttachedWindow` but it sets the origin of the window's frame to (500,500).

Comment: oh I see, the famous Matt’s window :) I believe that the best place to go for this kind of advice might be stackoverflow.com as more programmers roam that place. I do program in Cocoa/Obj-C but I have never used MAAttachedWindow (tho it looks cool!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Developer Tools installed, you could try running `Pixie.app` and configuring that to give you coordinates. It might calculate them differently.

Comment: Huh, there's an app I'd never heard of before. Awesome. +1 for unintentional discovery.

Comment: On a Retina Screen, it looks like Pixie gives much higher coordinates than CMD + SHIFT + 4 (~1330 on width instead of around ~670). It still might be useful but just pointing it out.